# Force domain password change in the future?

Tags: active-directory, password

I want to force all my domain users to change their passwords, but I want it to happen on a specific day in the future.  Is there a way I can automate that today, either using a GPO or PowerShell script, or am I better off waiting until the day of the change and then doing something like what is mentioned in this link?

[How to Force domain users to change password now](https://serverfault.com/questions/497287/how-to-force-domain-users-to-change-password-now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command you posted in the [linked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/497287/how-to-force-domain-users-to-change-password-now), and schedule it using a scheduled task.

Command using `dsquery/dsmod`:

```
dsquery user "OU=Sales,OU=New York,dc=internal,dc=AcmeCorp,dc=com" | dsmod user -pwd ChangeThisNow! -mustchpwd yes -u Admin -p APassword
```

PowerShell:

```
users = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase 'DC=contoso,DC=com'
$users | Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Also, remember that this will not force a user to change a password *immediately*, it will just force them to change the password at the next *logon*

Comment: Holy cow, I should get an anti-award of some kind for not putting those two together!  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that would be a Powershell script or some 3rd party tool (just guessing there's a third party tool, i don't know of any offhand.)

Basically you could create a scheduled task to run and set the users passwords to change at next log on.